# Moving autonomous robot form one location to another based on array

Tags: unity, c#, scripting, navmesh

I have a 3D model of a house, and I want an autonomous robot to move from 1 object in this house to the next one. I have it moving to the first, but it won't move to the second one. This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveTo : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform[] goals;

void Start () {
    NavMeshAgent agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
        agent.destination = goals[0].position;

    if (agent.transform.position == goals[0].position) {
        agent.destination = goals[1].position;
    }

}
}
```

I'm a complete beginner in code, please keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Start` method is only executed once at start and the NavmeshAgent won't start moving the object before the `Start` method finished. The moving happens between calls to `Update`.

So check if you reached the destination in your `Update` method, not your `Start` method.

I would also recommend you to use [`agent.remainingDistance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NavMeshAgent-remainingDistance.html) to check if the destination is reached. Comparing positions for equality is quite error-prone because even though [the == operator for Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) is overloaded for returning true even when the positions are just *almost* identical, Unity's definition of *close enough* might be different than yours. *If* you want to compare positions, at least do it by checking if their [distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) is smaller than what you would consider close enough for "being there".

Comment: You, sir, are awesome! Thank you so much for your help. I got it working. I learn so much quicker by asking simple questions and working by trial and error than reading endless walls of tutorials. Thanks!!